# Dynamic table created from CTE (parent/child)

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, common-table-expression, crosstab

If I have a very simple table called `tree`

```
create table if not exists tree (id int primary key, parent int, name text);
```

And a few rows of data

```
insert into tree values (1, null, 'A');
insert into tree values (2, 1, 'B');
insert into tree values (3, 1, 'C');
insert into tree values (4, 2, 'D');
insert into tree values (5, 2, 'E');
insert into tree values (6, 3, 'F');
insert into tree values (7, 3, 'G');
```

I can easily run CTEs on it, and produce an output giving me path like this

```
with recursive R(id, level, path, name) as (
    select id,1,name,name from tree where parent is null
    union select tree.id, level + 1, path || '.' || tree.name, tree.name from tree join R on R.id=tree.parent
) select level,path,name from R;
```

Which gives the output

```
level  | path  | name 
-------+-------+------
     1 | A     | A
     2 | A.B   | B
     2 | A.C   | C
     3 | A.B.D | D
     3 | A.B.E | E
     3 | A.C.F | F
     3 | A.C.G | G
```

What I'm wondering, is it possible to somehow project this output into another table, dynamically creating columns based on level (level1, level2, level3 etc), giving me something like this in return

```
id | level1 | level2 | level3
---+--------+--------+-------
 1 | A      |        |
 2 | A      | B      |
 3 | A      | C      |
 4 | A      | B      | D
 5 | A      | B      | E
 6 | A      | C      | F
 7 | A      | C      | G
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the maximum depth of your tree, I'd keep your approach and simplify it using array concatenation to produce the desired output.
So for a 5 level tree, that would look like this :

```
WITH RECURSIVE R(id, path) AS (
    SELECT id, ARRAY[name::text] FROM tree WHERE parent IS NULL
    UNION SELECT tree.id, path || tree.name FROM tree JOIN R ON R.id=tree.parent
) 
SELECT id,
    path[1] AS l1, 
    path[2] AS l2, 
    path[3] AS l3, 
    path[4] AS l4, 
    path[5] AS l5
FROM R;
```

PS : sorry for not commenting on Ziggy's answer which is very close, but I don't have enough reputation to do so. I don't see why you would need a windowing function here ?

Comment: Actually I have no idea what the max depth would be. Starting to think I might need create a table to keep my CTE output, then use a function to create + populate the table (I guess the real answer is that this is not possible in SQL).

Comment: Using a PL/pgSQL function would definitively be the PostgreSQL way to go. But do you really need dynamic columns ? If this output is quite difficult to create it's also difficult to use, unless you only use `SELECT *` statements.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL requires to always define the type of the output, so you can't have the columns `levelX` produced dynamically. However, you can do the following:

```
with recursive
  R(id, path) as (
    select id,ARRAY[name::text] from tree where parent is null
    union 
    select tree.id, path || tree.name::text from tree join R on R.id=tree.parent
    )
select row_number() over (order by cardinality(path), path), id,
       path[1] as level1, path[2] as level2, path[3] as level3
from R
order by 1
```

In the example above, the column `row_number` happens to match `id`, but probably that wouldn't happen with your real data.